# How to send an emoji?

Tags: c#, html, http, web

How can I post an emoji? If I place it in `url` instead of `+message+` I will get wrong url, because sign `"&"` makes url invalid and my message won't be send.

```
 string url = "https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send?user_id=" + user_id + "&message=" + message + "&v=5.31&access_token=...";
```

♥ - &#9829

Answer (score 2, accepted):

URL Encode you message by calling [`HttpUtility.UrlEncode` (link)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlencode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
string message = "&#9829";
message = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(message);
Console.WriteLine(message); // outputs %26%239829
```

This will cause your data to never make the URL invalid, but still be readable as `&#9829` at the destination. You may have to reference [`System.Web`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility(v=vs.110).aspx) in your project.